# Round of Eight tournament pairing combinations

Tags: probability

I notice recently that in a Starcraft tournament in the round of eight, there were 3 Zerg players, 3 Protoss players and 2 Terran players, yet none of the four pairings had a Terran versus Zerg matchup. What are the chances of that?

I computed an answer to this problem by writing a computer program that enumerated all the possibilities and counted those pairings in which a TvZ occurred, but is there a mathematical way to compute the odds without enumerating every possibility manually?

For example, lets say the players are Z1, Z2, Z3, P1, P2, P3, T1 and T2. One possible pairing might be:

```
Z1 vs P1
Z2 vs P2
Z3 vs P3
T1 vs T2
```

In this set of pairings there are no TvZ matches. What is the odds of this occurring?

Comment: So it is an elimination tournament? 4 games first round, 2 games second round and 1 game in final third round? Also, is every team equally likely to win?

Comment: No, we are only interested in the pairings in the round of 8. The rest of the tournament does not matter. So, there are 8 players and therefore 4 matches (each match is between 2 players). A set of 4 matches is a unique "pairing". What are odds of pairing not having a TvZ matchup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the game, so will assume that anyone can be matched with anyone else. I will also assume all pairings are equally likely. Let the Terrans be A and B. Choose A's opponent first. Maybe it is B, in which case no Terran is matched with a Zerg. This has probability $\frac{1}{7}$.

But maybe A is matched with someone else. The probability this is a non-Zerg is $\frac{3}{7}$. And if that has happened, the probability B is matched with a non-Zerg is $\frac{2}{5}$. So the required probability is
$$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{2}{5}.$$
This turns out to be $\frac{11}{35}$. In the language of odds, which is little used in probability theory, the odds are $11$ to $24$.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of pairings is clearly $\frac{8!}{2^44!}=105$.

How many pairings don't have a Zerg Terran matchup?

There are $\frac{6!}{2^33!}=15$ when the two Terran player play each other.

On the other hand, when the two Terran players don't play each other there are $3\cdot2$ ways to select the enemies of T1 and T2 and then $\frac{4!}{2^22!}=3$ ways to pair the remaining four players. So there are $18$ ways when the two Terran's don't play each other.

Hence answer is $\frac{15+18}{105}=\frac{33}{105}=\frac{11}{35}$

Answer (score -1):

Total ways of pairing from a **pool** of $n = (n-1)\cdot(n-3). . .\cdot3\cdot1 = (n-1)!!$

Total ways of pairing from **two groups** with $m$ and $n = mn$

---

Pairings when both *T's* together = $5!!$

Pairings between *T's* and *P's* and between remaining pool of $4 = 2\cdot3\cdot3!!$

$$Pr = \frac{5!! + 2\cdot3\cdot3!!}{7!!} = \frac{33}{105} = \frac{11}{35}$$

Odds are usually used for betting as odds against

Odds against = $24:11$

Comment: I think downvotes and delete recommendation have been given while I was in the process of revising a previous answer ! How can I avoid such occurrences (other than posting a new answer rather than editing it ?)